# Error: Firebase ID token has expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

On my server I'm seeing these errors when using firebase admin sdk `.verifyIdToken()`

> Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh token from your client app and try again
>
> Firebase ID token has "kid" claim which does not correspond to a known public key. Most likely the ID token is expired, so get a fresh token from your client app and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.

On the client side I'm doing this before every request between browser <> server:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
```

It's my understanding from reading the docs that this function will get a valid, non-expired token because the SDK in the background will refresh itself as-needed. Optionally, I can pass in `true` to this function to force a refresh.

Why does this `getIdToken()` function seem to be sending expired tokens to my backend?

It seems like to resolve this my options are:

1. Pass in `true` to force refresh every time I call getIdToken(). This is needlessly expensive because it will add the overhead of a whole round-trip network request from the browser <> firebase before the request from browser <> my server
2. call `getIdToken()` the way I am now - decode the token manually on the client side, check the expiration, if it is expired then call `getIdToken(true)` again to force a refresh and send that newly refreshed token to my server

Is number 2 the recommended/expected way to deal with this? It seems like something is wrong here...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am seeing similar symptoms.

Comment: @puelo Same, could you fix it?

Comment: @MartinDeSimone Nope. It does not appear to be happening often, so i did not have another look. It probably is caused by some time differences. It might be (without having any code from firebase) that the check for expiration does not give any buffer and thus could be right on the edge for some cases.

Comment: Firebase stores the token in a cookie, so after an hour or so, the token will expire. At this time, the user submits a request to the server (not knowing they have an expired token). The server reads the token and tries to validate it, but the validation returns "expired". So, as the answer's suggest, you need to validate the token each time before submitting a request. I'm not sure why Firebase documentation doesn't talk about this. It does seem like a bad design. Refreshing the page will force the firebase api in javascript on the client to get a new token again.

Answer (score 35):

The token expires after typically an hour. `getIdToken` will refresh the cached token if it is expired. Make sure you always call that on the client when you need to send the token to your server. If you cache the token and always send it to your backend, it will be expired at some point.

Also just in case, ensure your server clock is synchronized. It is unlikely but your clock could be out of sync for some reason.

Comment: "> `verifyIdToken` will refresh the cached token if it is expired" < Does this mean I need to call verifyIdToken on the client side before sending? I don't see that in the docs... I think you mean to say that getIdToken() will refresh... I am calling this every time before sending the request. I will check server clock

Comment: server clock is synchronized, this server is on heroku, doesn't seem to be a clock sync issue

Comment: Sorry I meant `getIdToken`. I apologize. It was late at night :) I fixed the typo. You need to call that whenever you need to send an authenticated request to the server.

Comment: That is in fact what I am doing: > On the client side I'm doing this before every request between browser <> server

Comment: Then the error is likely not related to expiration. Try decoding the ID token using https://jwt.io and inspect its content.

Comment: I am sending these tokens to my backend, getting this error: { Error: Firebase ID token has expired. Get a fresh token from your client app and try again. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token. When I inspect these tokens with jwt.io I can see they are expired

Comment: Then the error must be on the client side. The validation on the Admin SDK side seems correct. `getIdToken` should always return a fresh unexpired ID token but if the client side clock is off, it may end up returning an expired one.

Comment: But the question here is, is this a good design by firebase? Having a token that expires every hour and must be refreshed before sending it to a back-end server, seems like IMO a bad design.

I have seen that getIdToken() call take up to 10 seconds to return, so having a user waiting for 10 seconds is a very poor user experience.

I feel like I have to be missing something here?

Comment: Where did you get that it takes 10 seconds to refresh? There is no factual basis for that. The use of short lived tokens minimizes the window of attack and is a well established industry standard.

Comment: what you mean by `server clock is synchronized`? my server is in different time zone and my clients are in different time zone. Will it effect?

Answer (score 10):

Another possible solution above the mentioned, is that your browser (Or system) date is wrong. Is it almost always related to the date.

Comment: How browser or system time is related to token expiration? You are not validating token locally it gets validated on Firebase. So when you get token you get token expiration time  from frebase, when you are validating token you are validating it on firebase to so firebase chacks exp time on same mashine that issues token... so as far as i understand local time should not have ANY impact on it. If it does then your token issued for some time zone +4h will immediatly will be expired if firebase server is in +1 time zone. Or?

Comment: Don't know dude. I don't remember how much was the offset (Around a day I think), but with the wrong system date it did not work, once i changed it, it worked. And you can see by the upvotes that it helped someone else too.

Comment: Can hardly believe that :) Time offset would impact token if you would be issuing tokens by your self on one server and verifing them on another. Otherways  - exp time in token if set according to time on server that has issued it and checked on same server.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. But this answer still solves the issue sometimes, if you have time test if for yourself, with the system date wrong it won't work, I don't know if is the token or what. Sometimes you don't need all the answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
Error: Firebase ID token has expired
```

You will get this error when your device time is wrong. Check your device clock time as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using token on your backend, then you can do the following,

1.Check token on backend

2.If token has expired, send 401 unauthorized.

3.On the client, check if status code is 401 unautorized, if so call `getIdToken` and save new token

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem before and after some try and error, I found out that it was being caused by time sync.

I set my computer time and time zone to automatic and fixed the issue.
Also, remember to add "true" in getIdToken(true)

Comment: add true how, in place of your token

Comment: @MaduekweChukwuemeka here you can place the change getIdTokenResult(forceRefresh?: boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something more like this:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { (token, err) in

/* your code to manage error and success */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that there is an async way of getting the token?

```
            mAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult getTokenResult) {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;

                Log.d("testt", "time " + time + ", token " + getTokenResult.getToken());
            }
        });
```

Not sure, but I guess that it does internal checking and if token is not valid any more(for example there was a refreshed token broadcast for current user and it didn't reached to the user for some reason, network issue for example), it requests new one and returns that.

P.S. I am doing a research on this topic as well and will update if will find out anything new.

Answer (score 0):

const user = firebase.auth().currentUser

const { token } = await user.getIdTokenResult(true)

Try this. Using this method won't expire the token