# trouble making firebase authcheck with express/mongodb server from react

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, firebase, express, axios

I am working on a project that requires firebase authorization with a custom server. I am using mongodb with express and mongoose. Client side is react. The trouble i am having can be seen using the login page as an example.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import {
  CssBaseline,
  Box,
  Divider,
  Container,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  InputAdornment,
  Icon,
  IconButton,
  Avatar,
  FormHelperText,
  Button,
  TextField,
  Link,
  Grid,
  Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import Visibility from '@material-ui/icons/Visibility'
import VisibilityOff from '@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff'
import { auth, googleAuthProvider } from '../../../firebase'
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack'
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import useStyles from './login-styles'
import googleIcon from '../../../assets/google.svg'
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import useIsMountedRef from '../../../hooks/useIsMountedRef'
import AuthPage from '../AuthPage'



const initialValues = {
    email: '',
  password: ''
   
  }

  const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().email().max(255).required(),
    password: Yup.string().min(7).max(255).required('Password is required')
  })

  const createOrUpdateUser = async (authtoken) => {
    return await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/create-or-update-user`, {}, {
      headers: {
        authtoken
      }
    })
  }


const Login = ({history}) => {
  let dispatch = useDispatch()
  const theme = useTheme();
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => ({...state}))
  const {enqueueSnackbar} = useSnackbar()
  const classes = useStyles();
  const isMountedRef = useIsMountedRef();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('xs'));
  
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false)
  
  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible({ passwordVisible : !passwordVisible})
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && user.token) {
      history.push('/client-dash')
    }
  }, [user])


  const handleGoogleClick = async () => {
    auth.signInWithPopup(googleAuthProvider)
      .then(async(result) => {
        const { user } = result
        const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult();

        createOrUpdateUser(idTokenResult.token)
        .then(res => console.log(' CREATE OR UPDATE RESPONSE', res))
        .catch()

          //send snackbar success email sent
              enqueueSnackbar(`Welcome back, ${user.displayName}!`, {
              variant: 'success'
              })
        // dispatch({
        // type: 'LOGGED_IN_USER',
        // payload: {
        //   email: user.email,
        //   token: idTokenResult,
        // }
        // });
        // history.push('/client-dash')
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        enqueueSnackbar((err.message), {
        variant: 'error'
      });
    })
  }

  


    return (
      <AuthPage>
         <CardContent className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full py-96 max-w-320">
                   <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                  Sign in
        </Typography>
        <Button
        className={classes.googleButton}
        fullWidth
        onClick={handleGoogleClick}
        size="large"
        variant="contained"
      >
        <img
          alt="Google"
          className={classes.providerIcon}
          src={googleIcon}
        />
        Sign in with Google
      </Button>
        <Box
        alignItems="center"
        display="flex"
        mt={2}
      >
                  <Divider
                    style={{color: '#161616'}}
          className={classes.divider}
          orientation="horizontal"
        />
        <Typography 
          style={{color: '#161616'}}
          variant="body1"
          className={classes.dividerText}
        >
          OR
        </Typography>
        <Divider
        
          orientation="horizontal"
        />
      </Box>
       
         <Formik initialValues={initialValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={async(values, {
          setErrors,
          setStatus,
          setSubmitting
         }) => {
                  try {

                  const result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password)
                  console.log(result);
                  const { user } = result 
                  const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult()
                  
                  createOrUpdateUser(idTokenResult.token)
                  .then(res => console.log(' CREATE OR UPDATE RESPONSE', res))
                  .catch()

                    //send snackbar success email sent
              enqueueSnackbar(`Welcome back, ${user.displayName}!`, {
              variant: 'success'
              })
                    
                  dispatch({
                    type: 'LOGGED_IN_USER',
                    payload: {
                      email: user.email,
                      token: idTokenResult,
                    }
                  });

                
                if (isMountedRef.current) {
              setStatus({ success: true });
              setSubmitting(false);
              history.push('/client-dash')
            }


                  } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
            enqueueSnackbar((err.message), {
              variant: 'error'
            });
            if (isMountedRef.current) {
              setStatus({ success: false });
              setErrors({ submit: err.message });
              setSubmitting(false);
            }
                  }
        }}>
           {({ values,
                  errors,
                  handleBlur,
                  handleChange,
                  isSubmitting,
                    touched }) => (
                    <Form className={classes.form}>
                      <Field
                      name="email"
                      as={TextField}
                      error={Boolean(touched.email && errors.email)}
                      fullWidth
                      helperText={touched.email && errors.email}
                      label="Email Address"
                      margin="normal"
                      name="email"
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      type="email"
                      value={values.email}
                      variant='outlined'
                      autoFocus
                      InputProps={{
                                      endAdornment: (
                                          <InputAdornment position="end">
                                              <Icon className="text-20" color="action">
                                                 mail
                                              </Icon>
                                          </InputAdornment>
                                      )
                                  }}
                      />
                      <Field
                        as={TextField}
                        error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}
                        fullWidth
                        helperText={touched.password && errors.password}
                        label="Password"
                        margin="normal"
                        name="password"
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        type={passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        value={values.password}
                        variant="outlined"
                        InputProps={{
                       
                                      endAdornment: (
                                          <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <IconButton 
                                className="focus:outline-none"
                              aria-label="toggle password visible"
                              onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
                                edge="end"> 
                                {passwordVisible ? <Visibility/> : <VisibilityOff/>} 
                                
                              </IconButton>
                                          </InputAdornment>
                                      )
                                  }}
                      />
                      {errors.submit && (
                          <Box mt={3}>
                            <FormHelperText error>
                              {errors.submit}
                            </FormHelperText>
                          </Box>
                      )}
                       <Button
                         type="submit"
                         fullWidth
                         variant="contained"
                         color="primary"
                         disabled={(Object.keys(touched).length === 0 && touched.constructor === Object) || isSubmitting}
                        
                         className={classes.submit}
                       >
                         Sign In
                       </Button>
                        <Grid container>
                          <Grid item xs>
                            <Link component={NavLink} to="/forgot-password" variant="body2">
                              Forgot password?
                           </Link>
                          </Grid>
                          <Grid item>
                            <Link component={NavLink} to="/create-account" variant="body2">
                            {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                            </Link>
                          </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Form>
                  )}
           
                </Formik>  






                
         
      </div>
                </CardContent>
        </AuthPage>
    )
}

export default Login
```

the firebase function in handled in the onSubmit fuction. It sends the token to endpoint in the server.

```js
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router()

//import middleware
const {authCheck} = require("../middleware/auth")

//import controllers
const {createOrUpdateUser} = require("../controllers/auth")
//route
router.post('/create-or-update-user', authCheck, createOrUpdateUser)


module.exports = router;
```

i am using the authcheck middleware to verify the token.

```js
const admin = require('../firebase');

exports.authCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.headers.authtoken); //token
    try {
        const firebaseUser = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authtoken);
        console.log('FIREBASE USER IN AUTHCHECK', firebaseUser)
       req.user = firebaseUser;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        // res.status(401).json({
        //     err: "Invalid or expired token",
        // });
    }
    
};
```

however this returns a 401 token expired. i know the token is being sent because it is logged in the console. Im at a loss. i dont see any other way to write the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here on stack overflow. A simple time sync on the machine i am working on did the trick.

[Error: Firebase ID token has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803495/error-firebase-id-token-has-expired)